# CPU idle but waiting on Disk I/O (wait) on a LAMP stack takes forever sometimes

Tags: mysql, apache, google-cloud-platform, lamp, bitnami

Sometimes my server gets slow because the CPU goes into idle mode it seems.

Usually it only goes back to normal when I restart the server, but sometimes it goes back to normal by itself.

[image of CPU going idle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MvvJ.png)

It appears that the source of the problem is MySQL.

[image of MySQL process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaFVF.png)

The server remains slow even when only common requests are arriving. However, the problem usually appears after stress on the server.

Is there any configuration I can do in either Apache or MySQL to resolve this problem?

I tried to put some cache on the site and other things that would alleviate cpu usage to try to prevent this situation from occurring. However, every now and then it still happens.

Some infos:
Mysql: 8.0.18 - MySQL Community Server - GPL
Apache: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix)
I run my server on Google Cloud using the LAMP stack provided by Bitnami

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.